# Python3 Tkinter Grid not expanding to entire frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

app_title = "Wordle-Klon" # Appens titel.
app_font = ("Arial", 20) # Applikation-vid typsnitt.
app_background_color = "yellow" # Bakgrundsfärg för appen.

window_width = 1000
window_height = 800

class App(tk.Tk): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
        self.geometry('500x500') 
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.title = tk.Label(text=app_title, anchor="c", pady=20, font=app_font, bg='yellow', fg="black")
        self.title.pack()

        self.letterFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg="Blue")
        self.letterFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.createLetterSquares()

    def createLetterSquares(self):
        self.letters, self.rows = 1, 1

        for i in range(5*5):
            if self.letters == 6: 
                self.rows += 1
                self.letters = 1

            self.frame = tk.Frame()
            self.label = tk.Label(text="("+str(self.rows)+", "+str(self.letters)+")", bg="red", padx=10, pady=10)
            self.label.pack(in_=self.frame, anchor="c")

            self.frame.grid(in_=self.letterFrame, row=self.rows, column=self.letters, sticky=tk.NSEW)
            self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(self.letters, weight=1, uniform="True")
            self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(self.rows, weight=1, uniform="True")
            self.letters += 1 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    app = App() # Skapa ett app objekt. 
    app.mainloop() # Loopa appen.
```

I get a result that looks like:
[image: Result of current code]

How can I make the grid that is inside the frame, expand to fill the entire thing, rather than only using the minimum space necessary? I tried playing around with grid weights at the root (`self.app`) but it did not make any difference.

Comment: Can you please provide a **minimum** working example? Right now there is too much code to look through.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @TheLizzard ! I have now removed everything I deem unnecessary :) Because there may be weights outside the function that may affect the behavior I did not remove parts of the class.

Comment: I removed more that is unnecessary according to the site standards. Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: As an aside, please think carefully about the use of `self` in `createLetterSquares`. Does it make sense for all of those variables to stay around after the method is done, and for those values to be *part of the `App` object*? Methods can use local variables, too, just like ordinary functions. In fact, `self` is just a normal parameter in the first place; the magic happens when the method is called.

Comment: I am not set up to test Tkinter code, but did you try specifying `expand` for the `.grid` calls?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: `grid` doesn't have an `expand` option.

Comment: This code won't run. Please make sure the example is runnable.

Comment: I am not sure why no one is answering the question here. The way to make a `grid()` distribute the size of each widget evenly is to use `rowconfigure()` and `columnconfigure()` in the appropriate locations and then make sure to be using grid() on the correct widget in those locations.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I need to be able to change the label text and frame later on, therefore I kept the ```self``` command before the variables. Could you please elaborate on why my use ```self``` is inefficient? I am pretty new to classes and would love some feedback.

Comment: @NewDeveloper404 It is easier to store all your labels in a list or dict instead. This can make it much easier to manage those labels dynamically.

Comment: @BryanOakley The code should now be runnable, but not exactly the same as I, and other parties have made it minimal as per the request of TheLizzard.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I do actually store them in a list, but that part of the code has been removed by another party :)

Comment: @NewDeveloper404 change `self.Frame.grid_columnconfigure` to `self.letterFrame.grid_columnconfigure` and do the same for rowconfigure and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Mike-SMT That did help a lot! Thanks for the suggestion. Although I am running in to other problems now. It no longer shows the background-color I have set (yellow) nor the color of the frame the grid is located in (blue). Also, there is no margin at the top but there is a lot of margin at the bottom. Is there any suggestions you have that may help me here? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm talking about `self.letters` and `self.rows` (which will just be equal to `5` afterwards, and thus can't help find a specific label) as well as `self.frame` and `self.label` (which will **only** remember the **last** created element in the grid). If other code stores the frames/labels in a list, then fine; but the `self.frame` and `self.label` values are then still useless, and redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue was configuring row/column weights on the wrong frame. In this case the correct frame was `letterFrame`.

I have updated your code to include a list of all label objects so you can also have a reference point for how you can load all your labels into a list for later use.

SO is really for asking a specific question about a specific problem. If you have multiple questions its best to ask one at a time in a new post after solving the main issue.

Keep in mind that some behavior may differ in MAC vs PC. I am testing this code on PC. Since Tkinter takes a lot of its display from the OS environment your window may look slightly different from mine.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk


app_title = "Wordle-Klon"  # Appens titel.
app_font = ("Arial", 20)  # Applikation-vid typsnitt.
app_background_color = "yellow"  # Bakgrundsfärg för appen.


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('500x500')
        tk.Label(text=app_title, anchor="c", pady=20, font=app_font, bg='yellow', fg="black").pack()
        self.letterFrame = tk.Frame(self, bg="Blue")
        self.letterFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)
        self.label_list = []
        self.number_of_columns = 5
        self.number_of_labels = 25
        self.createLetterSquares()

    def createLetterSquares(self):
        row = 0
        col = 0
        for i in range(self.number_of_labels):
            self.letterFrame.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1, uniform="True")
            self.letterFrame.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1, uniform="True")
            lbl = tk.Label(self.letterFrame, text=f"({row+1}, {col+1})", bg="red", padx=10, pady=10)
            self.label_list.append([lbl, row, col])
            self.label_list[-1][0].grid(row=row, column=col, sticky=tk.NSEW)
            col += 1
            if col == self.number_of_columns:
                col = 0
                row += 1
        print(self.label_list)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()  # Skapa ett app objekt.
    app.mainloop()  # Loopa appen.
```

Results:

[image]